# react iframe displays blank page with base64 pdf data with IE 15 windows 10

Tags: reactjs, windows, pdf, internet-explorer, iframe

[React iframe](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-iframe) displays blank page with base64 pdf data with IE 15 windows 10. I tested it with browserstack. If I supply a real pdf file, it will work in IE.

Here is my [test project](https://github.com/kenpeter/test_popup_iframe).

Main code like this:

```
function App() {
  const meta = 'data:application/pdf;base64,';

  const data = meta +  
    'JVBERi0xLjcKCjEgMCBvYmogICUgZW50cnkgcG9pbnQKPDwKICAvVHlwZSAvQ2F0YWxvZwog' +
    'IC9QYWdlcyAyIDAgUgo+PgplbmRvYmoKCjIgMCBvYmoKPDwKICAvVHlwZSAvUGFnZXMKICAv' +
    'TWVkaWFCb3ggWyAwIDAgMjAwIDIwMCBdCiAgL0NvdW50IDEKICAvS2lkcyBbIDMgMCBSIF0K' +
    'Pj4KZW5kb2JqCgozIDAgb2JqCjw8CiAgL1R5cGUgL1BhZ2UKICAvUGFyZW50IDIgMCBSCiAg' +
    'L1Jlc291cmNlcyA8PAogICAgL0ZvbnQgPDwKICAgICAgL0YxIDQgMCBSIAogICAgPj4KICA+' +
    'PgogIC9Db250ZW50cyA1IDAgUgo+PgplbmRvYmoKCjQgMCBvYmoKPDwKICAvVHlwZSAvRm9u' +
    'dAogIC9TdWJ0eXBlIC9UeXBlMQogIC9CYXNlRm9udCAvVGltZXMtUm9tYW4KPj4KZW5kb2Jq' +
    'Cgo1IDAgb2JqICAlIHBhZ2UgY29udGVudAo8PAogIC9MZW5ndGggNDQKPj4Kc3RyZWFtCkJU' +
    'CjcwIDUwIFRECi9GMSAxMiBUZgooSGVsbG8sIHdvcmxkISkgVGoKRVQKZW5kc3RyZWFtCmVu' +
    'ZG9iagoKeHJlZgowIDYKMDAwMDAwMDAwMCA2NTUzNSBmIAowMDAwMDAwMDEwIDAwMDAwIG4g' +
    'CjAwMDAwMDAwNzkgMDAwMDAgbiAKMDAwMDAwMDE3MyAwMDAwMCBuIAowMDAwMDAwMzAxIDAw' +
    'MDAwIG4gCjAwMDAwMDAzODAgMDAwMDAgbiAKdHJhaWxlcgo8PAogIC9TaXplIDYKICAvUm9v' +
    'dCAxIDAgUgo+PgpzdGFydHhyZWYKNDkyCiUlRU9G';

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Iframe src={data}
        width="450px"
        height="450px"
        id="myId"
        className="myClassname"
        display="initial"
        position="relative"/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: By the way, what do you mean IE15? The latest version of IE is IE11.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IE doesn't support iframe with data url as src attribute. You could check it in [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#feat=datauri). It shows that the support is limited to images and linked resources like CSS or JS in IE. Please also check [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions//cc848897(v=vs.85)):

> Data URIs are supported only for the following elements and/or
>   attributes.
>
> - object (images only)
> - img
> - input type=image
> - link
> - CSS declarations that accept a URL, such as background,    backgroundImage, and so on.