# Print blob (pdf) in IE / Edge with typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, internet-explorer, iframe, blob

I want to print blob (pdf) using typescript. I tried below code which works in Chrome but not in Edge.

Code 1 (works for Chrome but displays blank while print in Edge) -

```
    const fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    const iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
    iframe.style.display = 'none';
    iframe.src = fileURL;
    iframe.name = fileName;
    document.body.appendChild(iframe);
    iframe.contentWindow.print();
```

Code 2 (works for Chrome but contentWindow is null so throws error for contentWindow.document) -

```
    const fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    const iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
    iframe.style.display = 'none';
    iframe.src = fileURL;
    iframe.name = fileName;
    document.body.appendChild(iframe);
    document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0].contentWindow.document.execCommand('print', false, null)
```

I have seen many questions but none of them are answered. I am using angular 6 so is there a direct method to achieve this or any library using which it can be achieved.

Answer (score 2):

The code doesn't work because IE and Edge both don't support iframe with data url as src attribute. You could check it in [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#feat=datauri). For more information, you could refer to my answer in [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57439796/react-iframe-displays-blank-page-with-base64-pdf-data-with-ie-15-windows-10/57457566#57457566).

So we can't print the blob pdf directly in IE and Edge. There're two workarounds:

1. Save it in IE and Edge then print it manually. IE and Edge have their own API for creating and downloading files, which is called `msSaveOrOpenBlob`. You could use the code like below:

   ```
   var blob = new Blob([byteArray], { type: 'application/pdf' });
   if (window.navigator && window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {  //if IE or Edge
       window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob);
   }
   else {
       var objectUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
       ...
   }
   ```
2. Using [PDF.js](http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/) to parse and render pdf. It uses a link like below to show pdf:

   ```
   http://your_webserver_address/your_PDFjs_foldername/web/viewer.html?file=your_pdf_address
   ```